# How to customise ordering of results (i.e. something other than alphabetical order for strings)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "Category" in sql server2008. It has 2 columns -ID,Name. I have inserted 3 Name in it as:

```
1.Case Report
2.Original Article
3.Letter to Author
4.Submmited Article
```

I have used following query to show table data:

select * from Category order by Name desc

it is showing result as:

```
4.Submmited Article
2.Original Article
3.Letter to Author
1.Case Report
```

But I want to show table value as:

```
2.Original Article
1.Case Report
3.Letter to Author
4.Submmited Article
```

please help me someone.

Comment: What is the logic/pattern to the desired sort order? Or is it just hard coded for those 3? In which case add a display order column and order by that.

Comment: No it may be several rows but the following three should be in the specified manner as i have said.

Comment: So can you extend your example to show the other rows then and where they fit into the desired sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you do not want to use an alphabetic sorting, I would suggest adding another column to perform the ordering by. For example, create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME varchar(50),
  SORT_ORDER int
)
```

You would populate the SORT_ORDER column data to match the ordering you need and can then get the sorted data with:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY SORT_ORDER
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM Category
ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN NAME = 'Original Article' THEN 1
             WHEN NAME = 'Case Report'      THEN 2
             WHEN NAME = 'Letter to Author' THEN 3
         END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do a custom sort, in that case you can add third column eg SortID int, and then order the result set by the SortID. eg

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM TableName
ORDER BY SortID
```